# Xcode 6 - need iOS6 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Preferences -> Downloads only shows ios 7.1 Simulator and ios 7.0 simulator.

My Deployment Target is 5.0.

Why can I no longer get at least the ios 6 simulator?

Running Xcode 6.0 (6A313)

Mac 10.9.4

And why does is only show "iPhone 5" as an option for the simulator? The 4S can run iOS 7...

Answer (score 2):

To get the iOS 6 simulator you need to download an older version of Xcode. Log into developer.apple.com and you will see this link:

[image]

That will take you to:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

You will then download Xcode 5 and have access to the old iOS 6 simulator. You can have both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 installed on your machine at the same time.

Comment: So basically if I want to support iOS 6 I have to switch back and forth between two versions of Xcode for testing?

Comment: Correct. There's no workaround for testing on a simulator other than to install an older version of Xcode and then test from there by switching back and forth. You can have them both installed and running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To add the iPhone 4S as a simulator: In xCode go to `Windows` -> `Devices` and press the `plus` in the bottom corner and add the devices that you wish.